# Should a GDAL Plugin be the same version as GDAL aready built into QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-plugins, ogr2ogr

Should a GDAL Plugin be the same version as the GDAL that's aready built into the QGIS version installed?

Or,can another different version of GDAL be built and it installed as a Plugin for QGIS, even though the version of GDAL is different?  Is it reading QGIS's GDAL installation or a standalone GDAL installation for the plugin?

I'm going to try and create a Ubuntu QGIS Lisboa plugin with File GDB support.  And, I'd like to do the same for Windows 7 QGIS Lisboa. It's going to be installed using a standard osgeo4w (rather than advanced) install, but I'd like to build a plugin for it.  The reason I'd like to use standard install is that I'd like to have all the standard Python, PostGIS and Spatialite packages installed as well, and not sure how to do that with "Advanced", and still get GDB support.

If I can't get QGIS to use a new GDAL plugin featuring GDB support, the I'd like to atleast be able to add another standalone version of GDAL, and use the command line ogr2ogr to convert File GDB to shapefiles and dbfs (for the additional domain tables). Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS is using a mixture of built-in and external GDAL tools. So you can not predict what happens if you mix GDAL versions.

For such use cases, I have installed the GDAL standalone Windows builds from [Link](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php) (which does not interfere with QGIS) to load and transform the data into a format that QGIS accepts.